# gsoap restful c++ client using streaming

Tags: c++, linux, web-services, rest, gsoap

How to write a gsoap restful C++/Solaris client, which should send a document(xsd__base64Binary) to webservice using streaming?

We tried writing a gsoap restful client without streaming and it is working fine. We generated a request xml (serialization-  soap_begin_send(--), soap_serialize(--), soap_put(--),soap_end_send(--)) using gsoap and then used soap_post_connect(---), soap_send(---),soap_end_send(---) to send the request.

We used MTOM for streaming in gsoap client and working fine. 
Is it possible to stream a document in gsoap restful client? Can we use MTOM in restful case?
If yes, could you please let us know, what are all the gsoap functions I should use for serialization and then to send that xml request?
And also, please share if you have any sample code.

Answer (score 0):

One way is take doc as string and send that string as arguments to server.
soapcpp2 will generate code for client/server for you.
[See here](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html) for more details.

I agree with this but if you have document which is huge size than you can devide it in part. Create your own header-data combination and devide document in packet and send as string.